# Required Field Off When Unchecked

Tags: apex, visualforce

EDIT 3:

Just to make things easier I have used my custom object and here is what is happening:

First: When the page loads:

[image]

Second: When the checkbox is checked:

[image]

Third: When checkbox is Un-checked

[image]

END EDIT 3

EDIT 2: VFP screen shot: does not even render the checkbox:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="prevent ..." columns="1" id="amount">    
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.isprivate}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="amount" />
            </apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField required="{!Opportunity.isprivate}" value="{!Opportunity.amount}" id="amId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

END:

Here is the screen mockup will give you an idea:

Checked:

[image]

UnChecked:

[image]

I have Visualforce page and below is the code and what I want to have is conditional on/off of validation on the page, if the user clicks on checkbox then condition enabled otherwise disabled and do not fire.

so I have `required= true` on the description

Visualforce page:

```
 <apex:actionRegion >        
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="TSection" columns="2"  >                 
           <apex:inputField value="{!author__c.Is_author__c}">
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="TSection" />
           </apex:inputField>

           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />               
              <apex:inputField required="true" value="{!author__c.Description__c}" rendered="{!author__c.Is_author__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!author__c.Audience__c}" rendered="{!author__c.Is_author__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>    
     </apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: At first required should be false, but when you check Is_author__c, required should become true. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have updated my question with screen shot to give you visualize

Comment: Does your user have access to isprivate field? goto any opp-ty and check it. Does it work for you  custom object ?

Comment: @IlyaLepesh: check out my EDIT 3, I have demonstrate the problem and I'm using exact code you have pasted except that I'm using my custom object and field names different but the entire logic is the same.

Comment: @nick-kahn wrap checkbox with actionregion, answer is updated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make `inputfields` required by checkbox value, provide attribute `required="{!checkboxField}"` for you fields.
Add AJAX support within `actionSupport` to your checkbox, where you could rerender required fields.

Given page utilizes opportunity standardcontroller, where you already have checkbox field:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="Section"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel for="bool" value="CheckBox" />
                <apex:actionRegion>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.isprivate}" id="bool">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Section"/>
                    </apex:inputField> 
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:inputField required="{!Opportunity.isprivate}" 
                value="{!Opportunity.amount}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

`actionRegion` will send only checkbox field to server during validation. Save will send whole form.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Can't we put condition in required instead of two inputField with rendered condtions?

Comment: @VigneshwaranG: good point and I'm thinking the same

Comment: are you using any apex code? does not seems to work on my end and also the formatting is messed up as well, the way you have on GIF space mine have more then one textfield so the both together in tight spot

Comment: i'm not sure if this will effect or not but i'm using custom object, can you paste the entire vfp and apex code the sample you have?

Comment: @nick-kahn, please check updated section

Comment: do you have any idea why i am getting `false` when i checked the checkbox or unchecked the checkbox, here is how i am debugging since my checked checkbox does not do anything `<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" oncomplete="alert({!author__c.Is_author__c});" rerender="opauthor" />`,  i will create a separate page and try your code now

Comment: !author__c is just binding, if you want NOT, use !!author__c

Comment: @IlyaLepesh Much more clear to see `{!NOT(condition}` than `{!!condition}` imo.

Comment: so there are two problems i'm facing 1) with your sample which I have posted in my question with vfp code and screen shot and its not even rendering the checkbox and 2) After implementing NOT i'm now getting true regardless checked or unchecked arggg any idea?