# Rendering PageBlocksectionItem Problem

Tags: visualforce, actionregion

I have asked the question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121496/required-field-off-when-unchecked?noredirect=1#comment172171_121496) but this question is part of contiunation and I have a road block and this time it has to do with formatting is messing up:

I have two version of code i'm pasting here:

```
1) Working but the formatting is messed-up
2) Not working but the formatting is correct
```

## 1) Working but the formatting is messed-up:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="stat2" columns="2" >

<apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Status" id="stat" columns="2"   >            
        <apex:inputField value="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="stat2" />
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>  
</apex:actionRegion> 


 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
    <apex:outputLabel for="url" value="{!$ObjectType.Items__c.fields.Is_Custom_URL__c.Label}"/>
    <apex:actionRegion >

        <apex:inputField value="{!Items__c.Is_Custom_URL__c}" id="url"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="stat4,stat5"  />
        </apex:inputField>

    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="stat5"  >
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
                      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.items__c.fields.Proxy_URL__c.Label}" />
                      <apex:inputField value="{!items__c.Proxy_URL__c}" required="{!items__c.Is_Custom_URL__c}"/> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>  

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

## 2) Not working but the formatting is correct

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="stat2" columns="2" >

<apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Status" id="stat" columns="2"   >            
        <apex:inputField value="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="stat2" />
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>  
</apex:actionRegion> 

 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
    <apex:outputLabel for="url" value="{!$ObjectType.Items__c.fields.Is_Custom_URL__c.Label}"/>
    <apex:actionRegion >

        <apex:inputField value="{!Items__c.Is_Custom_URL__c}" id="url"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="stat4,stat5"  />
        </apex:inputField>

    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="stat4" rendered="{!items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
  <apex:outputLabel for="Proxy" value="{!$ObjectType.items__c.fields.Proxy_URL__c.Label}" />
  <apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:inputField required="{!items__c.Is_Custom_URL__c}" value="{!items__c.Proxy_URL__c}" id="Proxy"/> 
  </apex:actionRegion> 
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: In the 1st part, instead of <apex:pageBlockSection id="stat5">, did you try outputPanel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as it was mentioned before you could have problems with alignment and label displaying when using component `actionRegion`.

Following structure helps you to have proper alignment together with labels.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>   
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel for="nameId" 
            value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.Label}"/>
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:inputField id="nameId"> 
                <apex:actionSupport />
```

And your particular example:

```
<apex:page standardController="items__c">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Status" id="stat" columns="1"   >   
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel for="statusId" value="{!$ObjectType.Items__c.fields.Is_Status__c.Label}"/>
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}" id="statusId"> 
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="section" />
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:actionRegion> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="section" columns="2" >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
                <apex:outputLabel for="urlId" value="{!$ObjectType.Items__c.fields.Is_Custom_URL__c.Label}"/>
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Items__c.Is_Custom_URL__c}" id="urlId"> 
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="section"  />
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!Items__c.Is_Status__c}"> 
                <apex:outputLabel for="proxyId" value="{!$ObjectType.items__c.fields.Proxy_URL__c.Label}" />
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:inputField required="{!items__c.Is_Custom_URL__c}" value="{!items__c.Proxy_URL__c}" id="proxyId"/> 
                </apex:actionRegion> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: 1+Thank you, I was rendering the pageblocksectionitem instead of pageblocksection, it working now!